# How can I include .pdf files when I publish but not in a search and replace in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

More specifically my problem is if I include a pdf in my project and set its build action to content so it gets copied to the server when I publish, is there a way to exclude it from visual studios search and replace feature.  Would a post build action be a solution to this?  I just don't want anybody to do a global search and replace in my project and mess up the pdfs...

I know I just said a mouth full so let me know if you need clarification.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the section headed "Find options" in the find dialog, there is an option titled  "Look at these file types". If you qualify the type as `*.cs`, it will only look in files with that extension. You can also enter multiple file extensions. As long as you don't include pdf files in that filter, it will not apply to them. An alternative is to define a folder set to search in by clicking the `...` next to the folder combo. Put your PDF files into a sub-directory of your project and exclude that folder from the folder set.

Additionally, as you have said, not including them in the project and using a post-build event to copy them to the output would also work.

I would qualify though that you are trying to solve a problem that shouldn't really be a problem. The onus is on the developer doing a find and replace to take care in doing so, and to not replace the contents of files they don't intend to change in the first place. **Find an replace can be a dangerous tool.**